# Nintex Workflow how to link Task table with History table?

Tags: workflow, nintex

I have a list which trigger a workflow when a new element is added.

I have 3 tables:

- The `table` which contains all the element.
- The Tasks are stored in the table `Task`.
- The history is stored in the table `History`.

I wanna know which user performed a Task.
The user is stored in the table `History` (this is done automatically by sharepoint).

**Question: How can I link the table `Task` with the table `History`?**

I am able to link the `Tasks` with `table` with this relation
`Tasks.FieldValuesAsText.WorkflowListId == id_of_the_table and Tasks.FieldValuesAsText.WorkflowItemId == table.id`.

I am also able to link the `History` with this relation `table` with
`History.List == id_of_the_table and History.Item == table.id`.